# Random forest: balancing test set?

Tags: python, random-forest, imblearn

I am trying to run a Random Forest Classifier on an imbalanced dataset (~1:4).

I am using the method from imblearn as follows:

```
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedRandomForestClassifier

rf=BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,random_state=42,class_weight='balanced',sampling_strategy='not minority')
rf.fit(train_features,train_labels) 
predictions=rf.predict(test_features)
```

The split in training and test set is performed within a cross-validation approach using `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` from scikit learn.

However, I wonder if the test set needs to be balanced as well in order to obtain sensible accuracy scores (sensitivity, specificity etc.). I hope you can help me with this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the imblearn [docs](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedRandomForestClassifier.html):

> A balanced random forest randomly under-samples each bootstrap sample
>   to balance it.

If you are okay with random undersampling as your balancing method, then the classifier is doing that for you "under the hood". In fact, that's the point of using imblearn in the first place, to handle class imbalance. If you were using a straight random forest, like the out-of-the-box version from sklearn, then I would be more concerned about dealing with class imbalance on the front end.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are basically suggesting that the undersampling is also performed on the test set when calling the predict method, is that correct?

Comment: Class imbalance is really only a problem for training the model, to prevent it from overfitting the classifier. Once it's fitted/trained, then the predictions don't depend on class balance, they are just evaluated individually according to the already trained model.

Comment: I understand. However, I am not sure whether this might still affect the evaluation of sensitivity and specificity. Let's suppose that in the cross-validation process at a specific folding the test set is made mostly of the majority label (let's say to be the positive one). The accuracy evaluation would therefore be biased toward high sensitivity values and low specificity, if I am not mistaken. Would this in fact be a problem? Can I assume that the cross-validation process compensates somehow for this?

Comment: Cross-validation is intended to help exaclty this problem. In each split, the built-in balancer in the classifier should be accounting for any imbalance. Now, how much undersampling it has to do will be greatly affected by the balance of each fold, but that should be countered by having multiple splits. If you're concerned, you can always use more folds, up to leave-one-out, when doing your CV. Again, I think the key is that you are using a classifier _explicitly designed_ for class imbalance. And, the standard advice applies, you can always try it both ways and see what the results are!

Comment: I am happy to help. I would encourage you to try both options, balanced and unbalanced, and come back and yell at me if I am wrong, in ALL CAPS if I'm way off-base!